# Casting spells that require sight through familiar sight

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, familiars, blind

Here is the setup:

- I play a sorcerer and got blinded and deafened at the start of the combat
- I use my action to use my familiar's senses, which leaves me blinded and deafened, which I already am
- My familiar (an owl) uses his movement and lands on my head
- I am 10 ft away from my ally, and I want to use quickened spell to cast haste as a bonus action.

Haste states: "Choose a willing creature that you can see within range". Technically, I can't see him with my own eyes, but I can with my familiar's eyes which are on top of my head. In a real-world scenario, I don't believe this would be a problem for a caster. However, my DM ruled that I can't cast it since it strictly states that you need to see the target.

Should this be allowed?